# asp.net convertion of date with mysql database

Tags: asp.net

which is better convert the date by database or c# to bind it on grid event rowDataBound ? ,
and why & when we use this or this ?

Comment: Convert the date to what..?

Comment: Are you formatting the date or converting it from one datatype to another?

Comment: from mm/dd/yyyy to dd/mm/yyyy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are converting the date to some other date, it would be more efficient to do the conversion in C# and save the database some processing.

If you are trying to *format* the date, use the [DataFormatString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.boundfield.dataformatstring.aspx) on the bound field.

Comment: so why there is sql convert date function ? and when use it ?

Comment: Well, there are plenty of instances when DB data isn't processed through another language.

Answer (score 0):

You don't "convert" the date on the scenario you describe; you simply format it according to your needs. The date should be a date type on the database side and on the presentation layer, whatever it may be, can be displayed according to your needs. For example in asp.net you can format your date on the GridView as follows:

```
<asp:boundfield datafield="SomeDate" DataFormatString="{0:MM/dd/yyyy}" />
```

or

```
<asp:boundfield datafield="SomeDate" DataFormatString="{0:dd/MM/yy}" />
```

Comment: thnx very much but is it faster or by database ?

Comment: There are many good reasons not to do it on the database side even if it was faster; one of them is that showing a date in a specific format is something that pertains to the presentation layer, not to the Data Access layer. I doubt that the difference in speed is significant to worry about that, regardless of which is faster.